# resolving javadoc files with Ant and Ivy

Tags: ant, ivy, ivyde

I'd like Ivy to fetch both the log4j .jar and JavaDocs. Right now, I am at a dead end. When If I use this in my ivy.xml ...

```
<dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.16"/>
```

... then I just get the .jar file. But when using this ivysettings.xml ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivysettings>
    <settings  
            defaultResolver="default"
            defaultConflictManager="all" />
    <resolvers>
        <url name="default" m2compatible="true">
            <artifact pattern="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
            <artifact pattern="http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        </url>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

... and this ivy.xml ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info organisation="foo" module="bar"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.16">
            <artifact name="log4j" type="jar" ext="jar"/>
            <artifact name="log4j" type="javadoc" ext="jar"/> 
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

... then I get this error message:
*java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple artifacts of the module log4j#log4j;1.2.16 are retrieved to the same file! Update the retrieve pattern  to fix this error.*

What I am missing here? How can I get Ivy to resolve both the JavaDoc and the .jar files?

edit: 
Thanks for all the fast and detailed responses so far. This is my updated ivy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=
                   "http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info organisation="foo" module="bar"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public"/>
        <conf name="compile" visibility="public"/>
        <conf name="master"  visibility="public"/>
        <conf name="javadoc" visibility="public"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="log4j"             name="log4j"       rev="1.2.16" conf="default->master,javadoc"/>
        <dependency org="javax.servlet"     name="servlet-api" rev="2.5" />
        <dependency org="com.someother"     name="proprietary-core" rev="1.2.3" force="true"/>
        <dependency org="com.someother"     name="proprietary" rev="1.2.3" force="true"/>
        <dependency org="com.someother"     name="scanner"     rev="1.0"   force="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Now I get this error message:

```
Buildfile: D:\workspace\foobar\build.xml

resolve:
[ivy:retrieve] :: Ivy 2.2.0 - 20100923230623 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:retrieve] :: loading settings :: file = D:\workspace\foobar\ivysettings.xml
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolving dependencies :: foo#bar;working@myhost
[ivy:retrieve]  confs: [default, compile, master, javadoc]
[ivy:retrieve]  found log4j#log4j;1.2.16 in internal
[ivy:retrieve]  found javax.servlet#servlet-api;2.5 in internal
[ivy:retrieve]  found com.someother#proprietary-core;1.2.3 in internal
[ivy:retrieve]  found com.someother#proprietary;1.2.3 in internal
[ivy:retrieve]  found com.someother#scanner;1.0 in internal
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolution report :: resolve 332ms :: artifacts dl 10ms
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   5   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   4   |   0   |
    |      compile     |   4   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   4   |   0   |
    |      master      |   4   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   4   |   0   |
    |      javadoc     |   4   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   4   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      :: log4j#log4j;1.2.16: configuration not found in log4j#log4j;1.2.16: 'master'. It was required from foo#bar;working@myhost default
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
```

There seems to be a problem with the Maven scopes. But what exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the pattern you are using in the ivy retrieve task. It needs to include the optional "classifier" attribute to ensure the file name is unique:

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[conf]/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
```

Classifier is a Maven thing, is used to identify additional artefacts associated with a Maven module.

### Additional observation

No need for complicated ivy settings. Configuration mappings control which artefacts are downloaded from other modules.

Remove the **ivysettings.xml** file and try the following in your **ivy.xml**:

```
<dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.16" conf="default->master,javadoc"/>
```

This results in the following files being downloaded:

- log4j-1.2.16.jar
- log4j-1.2.16-javadoc.jar

How does it work?

For Maven modules ivy creates a configuration matching each of the standard Maven scopes:

- master  : Main jar only
- compile : main jar, plus jars used for compile (This is also the "default" scope)
- runtime : Main jar, plus jars used for compile, runtime
- test    : Main jar, plus jars used for compile, runtime, test

and additionally creates a configuration for each additional artefact (or classifier) published by the module:

- sources
- javadoc

This enables you to mix and match.