# ivy (2.3.0 or 2.4) not resolving SNAPSHOT maven dependency with a classifier

Tags: maven, ivy, nexus

I am unable to resolve SNAPSHOT dependencies using ivy-2.3.0 and a nexus / maven 2 repo.

I have tried a couple of things but still it fails,

this **part** has been fixed: see my comment in the comment section.

> the latest output I am getting is that the maven:classifier is not
>   associated with an element. For this I need to fill in the namespace
>   mapping and not sure how how this should look for maven and ivy for
>   the classifier part.

my nexus is using timestamps.

my porject file

```
<project 
name="test" 
xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant"
>

<ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml" />

<ivy:retrieve pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" />

.....
```

my ivysettings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivysettings>

     <!-- what should I put here for maven and ivy to use classifier? -->
     <namespace name="test">
      <rule>
        <fromsystem>
          <src org="systemorg"/>
          <dest org="A"/>
        </fromsystem>
        <tosystem>
          <src org="A"/>
          <dest org="systemorg"/>
        </tosystem>
      </rule>
    </namespace>


    <credentials host="nexus"
                         realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
                         username="xyz" passwd="xyz"/>

    <property name="libs_snapshot"
                     value="http://nexus.host.com/nexus/content/repositories/libs_snapshot"/>

    <property 
        name="version_pattern"
        value="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"
    />

    <settings defaultResolver="repos" />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="repos">


            <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>  
            <ibiblio 
                name="libs_snapshot"
                m2compatible="true" 
                pattern="${version_pattern}"
                root="${libs_snapshot}"
            />


        </chain>
    </resolvers>

</ivysettings>
```

my ivy.xml file:

```
<ivy-module version='2.0' xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
    <info 
        organisation="com.xyz" 
        module="chained-resolvers"
    />

    <dependencies>
        <dependency 
            org="com.xyz" 
            name="cache_store"
            rev="1.1-SNAPSHOT"
            changing="true"
         >
         <artifact name="cache_store" 
                m:classifier="mobile" 
                type="jar" ext="jar"/>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Comment: I manage to resolve the part where ivy is complaining that.
maven:classifier is not associated with an element.

add xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven"

to the ivy module.

line so:

<ivy-module version='2.0' xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">

Comment: Problem is not clear to me. The following is an example of how to retrieve a snapshot artifact with a Maven classifier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804253/how-to-dowload-multiple-maven-dependencies-in-ivy-with-different-classifiers/7815627#7815627

Answer (score 0):

Although I got error messages saying that ivy could not resolve the dependencies,
there was actually http 401 errors saying that I was unauthorized.

By running the ant task with the parameter "-debug" revealed the real cause.

```
HTTP response status: 401 url=
CLIENT ERROR: Unauthorized url=
```

I had the security credentials added but there seemed to be a problem with the 
entry I had:

This one did not worked and solved my problem I had:

```
<credentials 
    host="server"
    realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
    username="username" passwd="password"
/>
```

This one worked:

```
<credentials 
    host="server.xyz.com"
    realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
    username="username" passwd="password"
/>
```